# unity Photon OnTriggerStay2D only works for host

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon

im adding perks (upgrades) to my game but they only work properly when you play alone, when multiple people are in the game, the functionality stops working.
when the player 1 (host) enters the trigger, a pop up message appears saying Press F to purchase etc etc.. but when player 2 enters the trigger, the message does not appear on his screen but on player 1's screen.

script:

````
    public void Update()
    {
        if(!view.IsMine) return;
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.F))
        {
            isPressingF = true;
        }
        else
        {
            isPressingF = false;
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerStay2D (Collider2D collider)
    {
        if(!view.IsMine) return;
        
        if (!ownedHalet)
        {
            if(collider.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
            {
                juggConfirm.SetActive(true);
            
                if (isPressingF)
                {
                    if(PointSystem.Instance.points < 2500 )
                        return;
                    
                    BuyPerkHalet();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ```
````

Comment: Have you added the script to both players?

Comment: the script is attached to a gameobject thats also an image in the scene with a box collider